# How can I make a timer last for a minute then stop

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am using a DispatchTimer to do something every second, how can I make it do Something for a set amount of time say 1 minute or 2 minutes?  Do I need anther nested DispatcherTimer?

My code is below

```
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dt = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();

    private void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan interval;
        interval = (TimeSpan)intervalPicker.Value;
        dt.Interval = interval;
        dt.Tick += new EventHandler(dt_Tick);
        dt.Start();
    }

    void dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //Do Something
    }
```

I would appreciate if you could help me thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `Stopwatch` class:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

private void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    sw.Start();
    ...
}

void dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // stops the timer after 66 seconds
   if(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds/1000 > 66)
   {
       dt.Stop();
       sw.Reset();
   }          
}
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. If the timer is started, say, three seconds before we set the clocks back for Daylight Saving Time, then the timer will run for over an hour. And if it's started just before the clocks are set ahead, then the timer runs for less than a minute. Same kind of thing can happen if the user changes the time. Better to start a `Stopwatch` when you start the timer, and then check the `Elapsed` property.

Comment: And add `sw.Reset();` after dt.stop in the if, if you want the start button to start another 66 seconds.

Comment: you are loosing the tick event here. it is difficult to achieve it exact tick using stopwatch

Answer (score 1):

[Cimbalino Windows Phone Toolkit](https://github.com/PedroLamas/Cimbalino-Phone-Toolkit) (available in [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/Cimbalino.Phone.Toolkit)) contains a DispatcherExtensions class with a BeginInvokeAfterTimeout() method that executes an Action after the specified timeout.

If you prefer, you can just copy the [DispatcherExtensions](https://github.com/PedroLamas/Cimbalino-Phone-Toolkit/blob/master/src/Cimbalino.Phone.Toolkit/Extensions/DispatcherExtensions.cs) file from the source code and use it in your own project.